# Boolean Value in Multipart Form-data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, postman

How do I pass a Boolean value as an input parameter to the Multipart form-data http post C# in both Postman and C# coding?

```
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Add(new StringContent("true"), "Customized");
```

I cannot directly give the true/false as one input parameter. If i give the value inside the string content, its not accepting as a boolean value. Is there any way to give the input parameter as a boolean?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
form.Add(new StringContent(myBool.ToString()), "Customized");
```

or:

```
form.Add(new StringContent($"{myBool}"), "Customized");
```